# Finding the infinite sum of a rational function using integrals

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

let's take the sum:

$$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{9n^2 + 3n - 2}\\\implies 9n^2 + 3n - 2 = 9n^2 + 6n - 3n - 2 = 3n(3n + 2) - (3n + 2) = (3n - 1)(3n + 2)$$

The simplest way would be to use partial fractions, and then convert this into a telescoping series. Which makes the sum extremely simple,  but I am looking for a way in, which I could use integrals, perhaps a definite integral in, which I could **derive** this sum. Any ideas?

The $f(n)$ is $f(n) = \frac{1}{(3n-1)(3n+2)}$

So can we use integrals?

Comment: It is not clear to me how to use the definite integral = number, its derivative is = 0.

Comment: If somebody wants to see details of solution using telescoping series, you can look [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1885317/check-convergence-and-find-the-sum-sum-n-1-infty-frac19n23n-2).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *I am looking for a way in, which I could use integrals, perhaps a definite integral in which I could derive this sum.*

**Hint.** You may write
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{9n^2 + 3n - 2}
&=\frac{1}{3}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{3n - 1}-\frac{1}{3n + 2}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{1}{3}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_0^1\left(x^{3n-2}-x^{3n+1}\right){\rm d}x\\\\
&=\frac{1}{3}\int_0^1\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(x^{3n-2}-x^{3n+1}\right){\rm d}x\\\\
&=\frac{1}{3}\int_0^1x\frac{1-x^3}{1-x^3}{\rm d}x\\\\
&=\frac{1}{3}\int_0^1x\:{\rm d}x\\\\
&=\frac{1}{6}
\end{align}
$$
The method by telescoping terms would be more direct here.

Comment: @OliverOloa, how can you switch the places of the integral and the sum? You had the sum outside, the integral inside, but then next, you took the summation inside and the integral outside. What allowed you to do this?

Comment: Also, how did you manage to evaluate that sum? The one inside the integral?

Comment: Let $f_N(x) = \sum_{n=1}^N x^{3n-2}-x^{3n+1}$. By the monotone convergence theorem,
$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\int_0^1 f_N(x)\ dx = \int_0^1 \lim_{N\to\infty} f_N(x)\ dx.$$
We can then evaluate the sum in the integrand using the formula for geometric series.